# Calculate sample variances from linear regression model for meta analysis?

Tags: r, regression, multilevel-analysis, meta-analysis, meta-regression

I want to perform a meta analysis in two levels using linear regression in R (with `lm()` ).
I understand that in the second level I should perform  a weighted regression with the weights being the inverse of the sample variances in the first level.

**How do you calculate these inverse sample variances from the output of the first level regression model (`lm()` model).**
Can you use the variances from the variance-covariance matrix as shown by `vcov()`? Why (not)? If not, how to calculate the sample variances?

To illustrate my problem I provide a simplified toy problem below.

In this problem I want to measure the effect of a study method used in different schools by different teachers. Teachers can teach in multiple schools.
In the first level I summarize the effect for each school (eliminate teacher effect) and in the second level I want to measure the effect of the method.

I'm aware you can solve this with mixed models but I want to know how to solve it through two level regression using lm() using inverse variance weights.

**EDIT** Note that the actual data I'm working with is rather technical and very large, hence the toy example.
The existing method of analysis on my data involves a mixed effect model but this is very slow given the amount of data.
There is a solution proposed to speed this up by splitting the mixed effect model in a two level fixed effect model (using 2`lm()`)
This approach is less performant but still satisfactory and much faster.
I'm looking to increase the performance of the two level analysis by including the sample variances from level 1 `lm()` as weights in level 2 `lm()`.

```
## generate some data
set.seed(101) 
dat = data.frame(
  method = factor(c('a','a','a','a','a' ,'b','b','b','b','b'))
, school = factor(c('one', 'one', 'two', 'two', 'two', 'three', 'three', 'three',  'four','four'))
, teacher = factor(c('Joe', 'Jane', 'Joe', 'Jane', 'Jef', 'Joe', 'Jane', 'Jef', 'Joe','Jef'))
)
dat$outcome = rnorm(nrow(dat), mean = as.numeric(dat$method) + as.numeric(dat$teacher))
dat
#>    method school teacher  outcome
#> 1       a    one     Joe 3.673964
#> 2       a    one    Jane 2.552462
#> 3       a    two     Joe 3.325056
#> 4       a    two    Jane 2.214359
#> 5       a    two     Jef 3.310769
#> 6       b  three     Joe 6.173966
#> 7       b  three    Jane 3.618790
#> 8       b  three     Jef 3.887266
#> 9       b   four     Joe 5.917028
#> 10      b   four     Jef 3.776741
level1 = lm(outcome ~ 0 + school + teacher, dat, contrasts = list(teacher = 'contr.sum'))
summary(level1)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = outcome ~ 0 + school + teacher, data = dat, contrasts = list(teacher = "contr.sum"))
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>        1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8 
#> -0.30048  0.30048 -0.65925 -0.04748  0.70673  0.57972 -0.25300 -0.32672 
#>        9       10 
#>  0.38001 -0.38001 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> schoolfour    4.5028     0.5183   8.687 0.000967 ***
#> schoolone     2.9402     0.5183   5.672 0.004765 ** 
#> schoolthree   4.5600     0.3992  11.422 0.000335 ***
#> schooltwo     2.9501     0.3992   7.390 0.001788 ** 
#> teacher1     -0.6882     0.3441  -2.000 0.116099    
#> teacher2     -0.3460     0.3441  -1.006 0.371493    
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 0.6915 on 4 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.9882, Adjusted R-squared:  0.9706 
#> F-statistic: 55.99 on 6 and 4 DF,  p-value: 0.0008178

## data is aggregated per school, removing the teacher effect
dat2 = subset(dat, teacher == 'Joe')
dat2$outcome = predict(level1,dat2)
level2 =lm(outcome ~ method, dat2)
summary(level2)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = outcome ~ method, data = dat2)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>        1        3        6        9 
#> -0.00493  0.00493  0.02862 -0.02862 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept)  3.97937    0.02053  193.81 2.66e-05 ***
#> methodb      1.58626    0.02904   54.63 0.000335 ***
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 0.02904 on 2 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.9993, Adjusted R-squared:  0.999 
#> F-statistic:  2984 on 1 and 2 DF,  p-value: 0.0003349

## use 1 / estimated variances from parameters in level1 model as sample variance
dat2$w = 1/diag(vcov(level1))[paste0('school',dat2$school)]
dat2
#>   method school teacher  outcome        w
#> 1      a    one     Joe 3.974444 3.722073
#> 3      a    two     Joe 3.984304 6.274351
#> 6      b  three     Joe 5.594250 6.274351
#> 9      b   four     Joe 5.537017 3.722073
level2_w =lm(outcome ~ method, dat2, weights = w)
summary(level2_w)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = outcome ~ method, data = dat2, weights = w)
#> 
#> Weighted Residuals:
#>         1         3         6         9 
#> -0.011940  0.009196  0.053379 -0.069304 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept)  3.98063    0.01985  200.51 2.49e-05 ***
#> methodb      1.59231    0.02808   56.72 0.000311 ***
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 0.06277 on 2 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.9994, Adjusted R-squared:  0.9991 
#> F-statistic:  3217 on 1 and 2 DF,  p-value: 0.0003107
```

Comment: Perhaps http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/tips:rma_vs_lm_lme_lmer will help you.

Comment: @mdewey thanks for helping. In the link you provided. they calculate sample variance with `escalc` from the `metafor` package.
I'm not sure how it's don inside the function. 
I really want to know, if possible, how to calculate it from a `lm()` model.

Answer (score 1):

Under different circumstances, I would post this as a comment and not an answer...but as this is an important issue, I'm going to opt for the more "permanent" approach.

The answer is that you can't use lm() for the 2-level analysis (with or without the variance-adjusted weights)...or, perhaps it is better to say that you shouldn't want to use lm().

Briefly, if you include the 2nd-level variables in an lm model (with or without weights, but in the scenario I'm about to describe, you should actually want to use the weights), you can obtain a separate measure for the effect of each of the distinct 2-level units.  However, you entirely lose the ability to generalize to the larger population.  And, as this is the implied goal with any meta-analysis, you really shouldn't want to do this.  Said another way, if you use a fixed effects approach (lm()), then you can state something about how these particular 2nd-level units are/aren't distinct from each other.  However, you cannot generalize anything to the larger population.  It is the mixed-effects approach that allows you to make this generalization.

Happy to provide clarification as needed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  I'm not interested in generalisation to a population but in inference only on the experimental units. 
I really want to try to calculate these sample variances in a two level fixed effect model.
I added a paragraph to the question explaining why I want to do that :)